# SOLVED: Docker container tunnelling through host to servers on network with RSA token

Tags: linux, docker, authentication, ssh

I'm facing what seems to be an odd problem, hoping for some help.

**Background:** For my day to day duties, I access a number of servers from my own machine (a Macbook pro laptop),
through a bastion host, then through another jump box and subsequently to the individual server I require access to. Like so:

`local machine -> bastion host -> jump box -> server`

I authenticate with the bastion host via an RSA (securid) token code (this is not the same as my ssh id_rsa key) and with the subsequent systems via LDAP credentials.
Eg: When I ssh to the Bastion I am presented with `Enter Passcode:` (My RSA securid token) whereas when I ssh to hosts beyond the Bastion, I'm presented with `Enter Password:` (my LDAP)

**Problem:** I have a number of scripts / tools which automate much of my day to day work, I would like to run these containers on my local machine as it's not permissible to run the containers on the boxes I connect through.
I have attempted to connect (by basic ssh) through a container running Debian on my local machine to one of the servers. I attempt to insert my RSA token as per usual but it fails when authenticating through the container.

Here is the docker command I'm running to enable ssh-agent forwarding from host to container:

`docker run -it --mount type=bind,src=$SSH_AUTH_SOCK,target=/run/host-services/ssh-auth.sock -e SSH_AUTH_SOCK="/run/host-services/ssh-auth.sock`

When I connect via:

`local machine -> bastion host` and use my RSA token, I authenticate fine.

Here is a snippet of my SSH config:

```
Host *
    ControlMaster auto
    ControlPath ~/.ssh/master-%C
    TCPKeepAlive true
    ServerAliveInterval=15
    ServerAliveCountMax=30
    ForwardAgent yes

    Host John-Smith-Bastion jsb  # Bastion Host
        HostName 10.0.2.123
        LocalForward 31590 10.101.10.12:22
        Port 321

    Host John-Smith-Jump jsm # Jump Host
        HostName 10.101.10.12
        ProxyCommand \ssh John-Smith-Bastion -W %h:%p
        LocalForward 127.0.0.1:2080 10.101.10.24:80
```

I'm not sure why the authentication failure for my RSA token is occurring when I try and connect via the container -> bastion. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 2):

**Solved**

Ok, so I played around with my SSH config.

```
Host *
    ControlMaster auto
    ControlPath ~/.ssh/master-%C
    #ControlPath ~/.ssh/master-%r@%h:%p
    TCPKeepAlive true
    ServerAliveInterval=15
    ServerAliveCountMax=30
    User waved218
    LocalForward localhost:8080 host.docker.internal:22
```

By modifying this section, it explicitly forces the connection to connect through the host.docker.container mapped to the localhost on the conatainer itself.

I also enabled container network to be the host itself.

The command I used was:

```
docker run -it --net=host  --mount type=bind,src=$SSH_AUTH_SOCK,target=/run/host-services/ssh-auth.sock -e SSH_AUTH_SOCK="/run/host-services/ssh-auth.sock" debian
```

Then within the container itself I used the ssh config file I modified (above). Obviously this was just for testing and a mount point or something similar will be used going forward.

When authenticating with the RSA (securid) token, it allowed me to authenticate through the container with the (tunnel through the host) when prompted - unlike previously.

Hope this helps whoever comes looking!